# Populate AMPscript variable with value from json?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, json

we have a json object in a data extension.
I would like to populate subject line depending on a field in that json.

How can I assign an ampscript variable a value from the json?

I tried this but that doesn't work:

```
%%[
var @Json 
set @Json = [order] 
]%%
{{.dataobject JsonVar type=variable source=@Json maxrows=1}}
{{.data}} 
{"target":"@Json"} 
{{/data}}

%%[
var @order_status
set @order_status = {{orderStatus}}
]%%
{{/dataobject}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.

Firstly, I would use `datasource` rather than `dataobject` as `dataobject` defines a global scope and while it makes the data available for reuse multiple times, the tags will need to be contained in section tags.

Secondly, you need to use the `TreatAsContent()` AMPscript function.

This should work:

```
%%[
var @Json 
set @Json = [order]
]%%

{{.datasource JsonVar type=variable source=@Json maxrows=1}}
{{.data}} 
{"target":"@Json"} 
{{/data}}

%%[
var @order_status
set @order_status = TreatAsContent('{{orderStatus}}')
]%%
{{/datasource}}
```

Comment: and what if you have a JSON with several objects and want to target a specific piece of the JSON? So for example when you have the follwing structure and want to target the second one?:

[{
 "test1": "1",
 "test2": "false"
 
}, {
 "test1": "2",
 "test2": "true"
 
}]